# CakePHP datasources in Django

Tags: django, api, cakephp, resources, datasource

I've been using CakePHP in several applications and now I'm building my first app in Django.

In CakePHP a [datasource](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/datasources.html) is the link between models and the source of data. It may be dependent on the ORM or may access data from external sources such as APIs.

I am trying to figure out how can I do the same in Django for Non-ORM datasources (such is Models by default) in order to play with an external API.

I'll really appreciate if you can point me in the right way.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This concept doesn't match up between django and cake.  In django models are explicitly an ORM that maps to a database.  Though I suppose you could write a custom backend that broke that rule, that seems painful.

However, there a many examples of using non traditional database sources such as using mongo documents with django. If you have a strongish understanding of python it would be relatively easy to design a base class that handles all the details necessary to wrap an API into an object instance.  But that isn't going to be something that exists out of the box in django.  There may be a third party app that provides that functionality, but I'm not aware of one off the top of my head.  Doing it yourself wouldn't be all that much more complex than the way you do it in cake, IE in cake a nondatabase datasource needs code to make the request and parse the response and such it doesn't just magically know how to deal with any API.

If you don't want to go the wrote of wrapping up all the behaviors of calling an api and constructing a model style class to contain all that logic, the normal approach to handling that in django would simply be to use urllib2 (if this is a remote api source) and to parse the results of the request.

Comment: Thank you John for your answer! Actually I already have a module that wraps the communication with the API. I am importing my module into a view and there sending the needed data to the template.

However, I think there should be a better/standard way to do that...for example, if I need to write to the API, how should I to define my forms ?

Comment: Well you won't have the nice stuff provided by ModelForms (unless again you reimplement the logic for the API backend).  You can however simply use a normal Form and handle the writes to the API from within your view code...or better yet, add a method to your Form that handles the writes.  You could even make a class that inherits from Form, but implements something like `def write()` and who's init accepts a url.  Then `write()` loops over the cleaned_data and posts the data correctly in a very generic way.